# Creating a new root certificate with new key length on windows ad certificate services

Tags: active-directory, ad-certificate-services

Due to new corporate guidelines I need to update the root certificate of my CA so the key length is 4096bits (Currently 2048bits).

My CA is AD integrated and currently running on our DC.

So now I am stuck at the point where I am not finding any kind of information if a simple "reenrollment" of the template of this CA is possible.

I have already had a look at this [microsoft learning page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/change-certificates-expiration-date) but it looks like there is not really an explanation for what I need to do.

Do I need to recreate the CA?

Comment: The key length for issued certificates is normally specified in the configuration file when creating a request. The key length of the root CA is normally specified when setting up the CA. Sounds like you need to"renew"/ re-create your root CA certificate with a 4096 bit key length.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback! It seems that not so much information are available out around my specific case. Yesterday I spended some time and got snapshots of my AD-Controllers where I tested the scenario "recreate the CA" and it worked pretty well.

Comment: So now I am going to schedule a maintenance for the upcomming week where the operation will be executed on the open heart ;D

Answer (score 0):

In case someone will ever face the same problem I faced here is the solution without reinstalling the role.

Especially this article helped me: https://www.scriptinghouse.com/2022/09/how-to-renew-root-certificate-of-microsoft-ca-with-a-longer-validity-period.html

I just created a new capolicy.inf with the increased key length and afterwards prolonged the certificate of my CA.

Kind Regards
Bad Santa

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).